# (How) Laravel Deploy with FTP

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, ftp, filezilla

I built a laravel project and I normally use localhost with the command "php artisan serve" to test my project

But now, I want to host on server.
I successfully connected my server with using FileZilla.
and I tested I can put a simple abc.html file and can be accessed with ___.com/abc.html

How to deploy my laravel project to my server?
Can I just upload the whole laravel project to server then can access without any command?
or must need to remote with SSH and install something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply drag and drop the root folder to your server's *root*. Not to the *public_html* directory. The only thing that should be in the public_html directory is Laravel's "public" directory (thus you have to rename it, depending on your server's settings).

**Do not** put your configuration files inside the public_html folder or anyone will be able to access them and steal your data.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that you pointed the web server to the `public/` folder? There is an `index.php` file in that folder that bootstraps the entire site.

Answer (score 0):

**Deploying to Shared Hosting:**

Zip your project and upload it to `public_html` and Extract it

Create Database in mysql databases ( in cPanel )

Import .sql file from local phpmyadmin to online hosting

Now go to `public_html` and edit `.env` file, change the following

```
DB_DATABASE=yourdatabasename
DB_USERNAME=database username
DB_PASSWORD=database password
```

and now just open yourwebsite.com and your app will be there !

**Deploying On Cloud Hosting**

First of all go to your site or host/phpmyadmin and create new database and upload your sql database file ( which you can import from local phpmyadmin )

**Create Drop and upload all files**

Click on create new droplet and select LAMP from applications tab , now upload all files to your droplets folder `(/var/www/html)` through filezilla

Note : Make sure you changed database username , password and name in .env before uploading

**Connect to droplet through SSH (Putty)**
Now connect to droplet through putty and run below commands

> chgrp -R www-data /var/www/html
>
> chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/.env
>
> chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/storage
>
> chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/bootstrap
>
> chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/public/uploads

**Enable Modules**

Run below command to enable mod_rewrite module

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Now open 000-default.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Add below lines below

```
 AllowOverride all
```

Now restart apache2 server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

That's it now go to your site.com and app will be dancing there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I use AWS as my cloud database. so should I start at "Create Drop and upload all files"?

Comment: I think (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ARpTKWc6lQ) this video will help you. However this guy is doing fresh installation you should first push your all project files to public directory and then do the mentioned steps. And that's it! @WalkerBase