# PHP deploy on server (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, server

I have built a Laravel PHP Project

For my local testing,

First way: "php artisan serve" on the project root directory
   ---> localhost:8000/item

Second way: "php -S localhost:8080" in the public folder
   ---> localhost:8080/item

However, when upload my laravel project to server via FileZilla.

It returns HTTP Error 500 when "xxx.com/item"
but I can see "xxx.com/index.html" when I put index.html on the same directory

How to deploy the project? need to install or config something? SSH?

Thanks

Comment: Check permissions granted to the files

Comment: So local testing works then is what I'm gathering?  500 means an internal server error, so check your web server logs.  Likely permission issues.  You also need to make sure that the public folder matches your web root directory.

Comment: but I have no run any command on the server like "php ..."

Answer (score 0):

I have already answered a question like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510520/how-laravel-deploy-with-ftp/38511027#38511027)

Archive/Compress/Zip your project and upload it to `public_html` and Extract it

Create a Database in mysql databases ( in cPanel )

Import `.sql` file from local `phpmyadmin` to online hosting

Now go to `public_html` and edit `.env` file, change the following

```
DB_DATABASE=DatabaseName
DB_USERNAME=DatabaseUsername
DB_PASSWORD=DatabasePassword
```

and now just open yourwebsite.com and your app will be there !

Comment: I put my project into the public_html, but it returns HTTP 500 error

Comment: Did you follow all these steps @WalkerBase ?

Comment: that Laravel actually is a headache

Answer (score 0):

you have to link your domain path to /public in your project or you could use .htaccess file on root folder to redirect it in /public folder. Because public folder contains the index.php file.

Comment: but it is fine if I put the index.html -> "hello world" in the public folder