# Unable to add laravel 5 project to subfolder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I added my laravel 5 project to shared host server using this tutorial,
http://laravel.io/forum/12-29-2015-hosting-laravel-5-on-subdomain#reply-30462

This is my file structure,

```
domain.com/
|--larco
|-- public_html/
|   |--laravel
```

**public/index.php in laravel folder,**

```
require __DIR__.'/../../../larco/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../../larco/bootstrap/app.php';
```

**bootstrap/app.php file,**

```
realpath(__DIR__.'/../../larco/')
```

**bootstrap/autoload.php,**

```
require __DIR__.'/../../larco/vendor/autoload.php';
$compiledPath = __DIR__.'/../../larco/cache/compiled.php';
```

My laravel version is laravel 5.2. And after I loaded 'http://domain.com/laravel/public/' link I get 'Whoops, looks like something went wrong.' issue. It would be great help if someone can look into it.

This is the issue added in storage/logs/laravel.log

> production.ERROR: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'No
>   supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are
>   invalid.' in
>   /home/silverdr/larco/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php:45

This is my env file...

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:tcPLEQN5yC984pB8EVHsdR/hLNFtq0hBasH+LMFBO+M=
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=myuser
DB_PASSWORD=mypass

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: enable debug mode and see what the actual error is

Comment: Or check your logs `storage/llogs/laravel.log`.

Comment: @james, I checked error log and updated the question. Thanks a bunch

Comment: @vimuth please run `php artisan key:generate` and let me know how that goes

Comment: @vimuth check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After ao many false attempts change Encryption Key cipher to MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 worked for me.

I changed in config/app.php,

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

'cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
```

- MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 Should be without quotes.

Comment: Why the down vote?, And @iftikar if this is about revenge I didn't dovnvote you...

Answer (score 1):

I found another easier way to do this. We just have to create a folder in shared domain and,

1. Change the name of server.php file to 'index.php'.
2. Copy .htaccess file from public folder to main directory(Created subfolder)
3. And inside .htaccess after **RewriteEngine On** we have to add 
   RewriteBase /yoursubfolder/

My laravel version is 5.2 and this works for me. I'm adding this as different answer because this is not the actual answer but this was really helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you guys are confused in deploying Laravel app to shared hosting.It is just simple i already answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510520/how-laravel-deploy-with-ftp/38511027#38511027) but for the sake of new question let me explain.

**Deploying Laravel Project to Shared Hosting :**

1. Zip your project and upload it to `public_html` and extract it
2. Now create a new database in mysqldatabases ( in your hosting cPanel )
3. Next is to import your local database `.sql` file from local phpmyadmin to online hosting phpmyadmin
4. Next step is go to the project folder and edit the following in `.env` file

> `DB_DATABASE=yourdatabasename`
>
> ```
> DB_USERNAME=databaseusername
>
> DB_PASSWORD=databasepassword
> ```

and that's it now your project will be live on, `yoursite.com/yourproject`

Here is a Video in which i deployed my app to subdirectory: [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9M3NwcgY28k)